# ¿Como puedo centrar este formulario materialize?

Tags: css, html5, materialize, material-design

he tenido este problema con el framework css Materialize, estoy recién usándolo, tengo este formulario que quiero centrar, lo intenté con "center" como clase y como display:flex; justify-content: center; al hacer eso se iba a la derecha, así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```html
     <div class="container">  
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12 center-a">
                <div class="browser-default col s3">
                    <input class="browser-default num-input" id="num1" placeholder="Ingrese un número" type="number"
                     class="validate">
                </div>

                <div class="col s3">
                    <select class="browser-default unit-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Unidad</option>
                        <option>ug</option>
                        <option>mg</option>
                        <option>g</option>
                        <option>Kg</option>
                        <option>Ton</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Recordar que está hecho con materialize.
Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PROBLEMA**

Tienes 2 elementos `col` dentro de otro elemento `col`, cosa que no es lo correcto cuando trabajas con el sistema de [grilla](https://materializecss.com/grid.html) de [Materialize](https://materializecss.com/):

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> <!-- Elemento ROW -->
    <div class="col s12 center-a"> <!-- Elemento COL (BIEN) -->
      <div class="browser-default col s3"> <!-- Elemento COL (MAL) -->
        <input class="browser-default num-input" id="num1" placeholder="Ingrese un número" type="number" class="validate"> <!-- Usas 2 veces el atributo class ??? -->
      </div> <!-- Finaliza primer COL interno -->
      <div class="col s3"> <!-- Elemento COL (MAL) -->
        <select class="browser-default unit-select">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>Unidad</option>
          <option>ug</option>
          <option>mg</option>
          <option>g</option>
          <option>Kg</option>
          <option>Ton</option>
        </select>
      </div> <!-- Finaliza segundo COL interno
    </div> <!-- Finaliza COL externo
  </div> <!-- Finaliza ROW -->
</div> <!-- Finaliza CONTAINER -->
```

De la documentación de Materialize (traducción propia):

> **Las Columnas viven dentro de las Filas**
>
> Recuerda cuando estés creando tu diseño, que todas las columnas deben estar contenidas dentro de una fila, y que debe agregar la clase `col` a los elementos `div` internos para convertirlos en `columnas`.

Si bien, parece que puedo agregar la clase `col` a cualquier elemento `div`, siempre y cuando se encuentre dentro de una fila, realmente lo que se debe asegurar es que una columna sea hijo inmediato de una fila, de esta forma la grilla funcionará correctamente, además de ser un diseño mucho más lógico.

**SOLUCIÓN**

Dicho lo anterior, y suponiendo que lo que deseas es centrar tus dos elementos de columna, una posible solución es deshacerte del elemento `col` externo, ya que estaría demás, impidiendo que los estilos aplicados para centrar el contenido surtan el efecto deseado.

Por ejemplo:

```css
.col {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.dashed {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
    <div class="col s6 m5 l4 dashed">
      <input class="browser-default num-input validate" id="num1" placeholder="Ingrese un número" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 m5 l4 dashed">
      <select class="browser-default unit-select">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Unidad</option>
        <option>ug</option>
        <option>mg</option>
        <option>g</option>
        <option>Kg</option>
        <option>Ton</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Como puedes observar, no hace falta centrar horizontalmente ya que la clase `container` realiza el alineamiento por nosotros, lo que si debes hacer es establecer los diferentes tamaños de columna de acuerdo al tamaño del `viewport`. Para pantallas grandes (`l`) o extra grandes (`xl`) no hay problema de elementos que ocupen 4 columnas (`l4`), pero para pantallas pequeñas (`s`) el espacio debes aprovecharlo al máximo, por lo tanto podrías usar elementos que ocupen 6 columnas (`s6`).

Por otro lado, he sobre escrito la clase `col`, para asignarle un valor de margen izquierdo y derecho en automático, de esta forma el contenido queda centrado en la columna y no alineado a la derecha (este es el comportamiento por defecto en los estilos de Materialize CSS):

```css
/* CSS de elemento col s3 en Materialize CSS*/
.row .col.s3 {
  width: 25%;
  margin-left: auto; /* empuja los elementos hacia la derecha */
  left: auto;
  right: auto;
}
```

Además, le he añadido la clase `valign-wrapper` al elemento de fila, para centrar verticalmente los elementos en la misma.

Por otro lado, he añadido un borde tipo `dashed` para que se aprecie la alineación de los elementos de columna.

Como utilizas la clase `browser-default` para el elemento de tipo `input`, puedes notar que el mismo no se alinea correctamente en su contenedor, esto podrías corregirlo agregando una clase a dicho elemento para establecer su anchura al 100% de su contenedor:

```css
.custom-input {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Que puedes aplicar de esta forma:

```css
.custom-input {
  width: 100%;                 /* 100% del ancho del contenedor */
}
.col {
  margin: 0 auto;              /* Posiciona el elemento en el centro */
}
.dashed {
  border: 1px dashed black;    /* Sólo para visualizar el efecto */
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
    <div class="col s6 m5 l4 dashed">
      <input class="browser-default num-input validate custom-input" id="num1" placeholder="Ingrese un número" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 m5 l4 dashed">
      <select class="browser-default unit-select">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Unidad</option>
        <option>ug</option>
        <option>mg</option>
        <option>g</option>
        <option>Kg</option>
        <option>Ton</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Espero que esto te ayude a solucionar el problema.

**EDICIÓN**

Dado que deseas que los elementos queden juntos al centro, debes aplicar individualmente estilos a las columnas de los extremos. En este caso particular, las columnas sólo son dos, por lo tanto debes aplicar a ambas un estilo particular.

Por ejemplo, podríamos aplicar un estilo para establecer el margen derecho a cero (0) y el izquierdo a `auto` a la columna izquierda y lo contrario a la columna de la derecha, además usamos `!important` para dar énfasis a la precedencia de nuestra clase.

```css
.custom-align-right {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.custom-align-left {
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

Luego lo puedes aplicar así:

```css
.custom-input {
  width: 100%;                 /* 100% del ancho del contenedor */
}
.dashed {
  border: 1px dashed black;    /* Sólo para visualizar el efecto */
}
.col.custom-align-right {
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: 0 !important;
}
.col.custom-align-left {
  margin-right: auto !important;
  margin-left: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row valign-wrapper">
    <div class="col s6 m5 l4 dashed custom-align-right">
      <input class="browser-default num-input validate custom-input" id="num1" placeholder="Ingrese un número" type="number">
    </div>
    <div class="col s6 m5 l4 dashed custom-align-left">
      <select class="browser-default unit-select">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Unidad</option>
        <option>ug</option>
        <option>mg</option>
        <option>g</option>
        <option>Kg</option>
        <option>Ton</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

De esta forma, estás *empujando* el elemento de la derecha hacia la izquierda y el elemento de la izquierda hacia la derecha, teniendo como resultado que queden *pegados* en el centro.

Comment: Ooh muchas muchas gracias por la extensa explicación, tendré todo eso en cuenta. Ahora  mismo está centrado bien para todos los dispositivos pero con una separación al medio en la versión de pantalla notebook. ¿Cómo podría hacer que estén juntos?

Comment: Basta con *empujar* el contenido de las columnas, o usar `flex-box`. Dependiendo de lo que quieras lograr. Editaré la respuesta para que lo veas.

Comment: Funcionó correctamente, muchísimas gracias por todo

Comment: Puedes aceptar la respuesta como válida, eso te da reputación a ti, y también a mi. ;)

Comment: si claro, creo que ahí está, lo tuve que buscar en google para saber xD

Answer (score 2):

¿Me parece que te referías a esto? ¿O te referías a que ambos quedaran juntos y centrados?
Espero haberte ayudado, pero si no, puedes decirme e intentamos. La respuesta que te dí la encontre de [StackOverflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50671682/center-align-items-in-materializecss-row) de donde también podrías guiarte.

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">  
        <div class="row" style="float: none; margin: 0 aut;">
            <div class="col s12" style="float: none; margin: 0 aut;">
                <div class="browser-default col s3">
                    <input class="browser-default num-input" id="num1" placeholder="Ingrese un número" type="number"
                     class="validate">
                </div>

                <div class="col s3" style="float: none; margin: 0 aut;">
                    <select class="browser-default unit-select">
                        <option value="0" disabled selected>Unidad</option>
                        <option>ug</option>
                        <option>mg</option>
                        <option>g</option>
                        <option>Kg</option>
                        <option>Ton</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     
         <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

     </body>
```

Comment: Gracias por responder, si disculpa, necesito el input y el select centrados y juntos, ah y claro que probé con lo que me dijiste y el enlace que me dijiste.